# Wrap Div Around All Paragraphs Except 1st Paragraph

Tags: jquery, html, css, insertafter

Can't get this to work properly so it works on each post.

https://jsfiddle.net/haymanpl/htuczx5q/

```
<p>This is an example of a WordPress post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>

<div class="text">

<p>This is an example of a WordPress post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>
```

This is an example of a WordPress post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.

```
 </div>

$( "p:first-child" ).after(function() {

    return '<div class="text">';

    });
```

This works but it adds the closing div tag which i don't want as i need to add it using last-child.

```
   $('p:first-child').after( $('<div class="text">') );
```

I'm trying to wrap multiple paragraphs in a div excluding the first. I need to insert the  after the 1st paragraph and then the closing  after the last paragraph.

Comment: You can't insert partial or unclosed tags.

Comment: What do you mean "i don't want as i need to add it using last-child"? Are you trying to wrap one or more elements in a `span`? If so, update your question.

Comment: ya look into `.wrap` for jquery

Comment: Your title asks about divs but your code mentions spans. Which one is it?

Comment: <span class="text"> This is what i want to enter. I'm trying to wrap multiple paragraphs in a span excluding the first.

Comment: span is an intra-paragraph element so you shouldn't wrap p inside a span tag. (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1).  You can possibly do what you need by wrapping them inside a div.  What is it that you need to do?

Comment: Updated, How can i insert div instead of span to wrap the 2nd and subsequent paragraphs in a div?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/htuczx5q/3/

```js
$('p').not('p:first').wrap('<span class="text" />')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is an example of a WordPress post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>


<p>This is an example of a WordPress post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>
```

I've used `jQuery wrap`. It will wrap all the `paragraph` except the `first paragraph`.

To target a particular post (paragraph) then it can be done by three ways:

**ClassName**
`$('p.className').not('p:first').wrap('<span class="text" />');`

**ID**
`$('p#id').not('p:first').wrap('<span class="text" />');`

**data-attribute**
`$('p[data-attr="post1"]').not('p:first').wrap('<span class="text" />');`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Helps yes however it effects all posts. I need the code to effect each single entry without it effecting all posts in archive.

Comment: @Dev Then I will suggest, target the post by `classname` or `id`  or `data-attribute`. Let me updated the answer that will help you.

Comment: Gave you the big 25 but it still doesn't work on archives which contain multiple posts because it effects all posts.

Comment: @Dev I've one last question, how you are going to identify which post you are going to wrap with a div? You have any class or data-attribute?

Comment: I can use either .entry or .post.

Comment: @Dev `.entry` & `.post` are classname I assume. Is that correct?